# Auto-detect first meaningful line in excel using R

Tags: r

I have some excel files that I want to read using R (I am using the `openxlsx` library, but this can change if needed). My issue is that the database I want to access is not in the first row (actually, it's usually in row 3 OR 4, depending on the file).

I know that I can instruct R to read from a specific row, but I don't know what to do if the actual row number is unknown.

To make matters a bit worse, the first 3 or 4 lines are not completely empty (at least one line has some dummy content (a cell or two are non-empty).

Any ideas?

Comment: By excel do you mean `.csv` or `.xls/.xlsx` files.

Comment: I mean .xlsx files